# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client(after redirect)

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

My express app:

```
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const logger = require("morgan");
const compression = require("compression");
const session = require("express-session");
const pgSession = require("connect-pg-simple")(session);
const api = require("../server/routes");
const pool = require("../config/database");
/** ====== DotENV configuration */
dotenv.config({ path: require("find-config")(".env") });

const configurations = {
    production: { ssl: true, port: process.env.PORT, hostname: "" },
    development: {
        ssl: false,
        port: process.env.PORT,
        hostname: process.env.STAGE_HOSTNAME,
    },
};

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = configurations[environment];

const {
    responseHandlerMiddleware,
    sessionChecker,
} = require("../server/middlewares");

const app = express();

var credentials = {
    // key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/myresorts.in/privkey.pem"),
    // cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/myresorts.in/fullchain.pem"),
};

let server = config.ssl
    ? https.createServer(credentials, app)
    : http.createServer(app);

app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "20mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
    session({
        store: new pgSession({
            pool,
            tableName: "session",
        }),
        name: "user_sid",
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: true,
        cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 60000 * 5 },
        saveUninitialized: true,
    })
);


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }
    return next();
});
app.get("/", sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/login");
});
app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "../views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("../public"));
app.use("/", sessionChecker, api);
// app.use(responseHandlerMiddleware);

app.route("/login").get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    res.render("pages/login");
});
app.route("/register").get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    res.render("pages/register");
});
app.route("/dashboard").get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.render("pages/dashboard");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});

module.exports = server;
```

Session handler middleware:

```
const sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("sesson ---------", req.session);
    console.log("cookies ---------", JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    } else {
        return next();
    }
};
```

Every time I trying to to do a signup, this error keeps popping up multiple times:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/deep/Node_API/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/home/deep/Node_API/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:915:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/home/deep/Node_API/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:953:18)
    at sessionChecker (/home/deep/Node_API/server/middlewares/session.middleware.js:5:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/deep/Node_API/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/deep/Node_API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
    at /home/deep/Node_API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (/home/deep/Node_API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
```

I'm trying to make a session management app using express-session. It should be able to preserve the session and if the session exists it should redirect to the dashboard else should redirect to the login page.

UPDATE:
As robert suggested in the comments, the issue was here:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }
    return next();
});
```

I changed it to:

```
else {
  return next();
}
```

The error is fixed, but it is still not getting redirected to the dashboard after registering a user. Instead, gets called in the following manner multiple times:

```
GET /dashboard 302 246.426 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 247.005 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 245.620 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 247.940 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 246.114 ms - 64
```

I checked that this doesn't even get called:

```
app.route("/dashboard").get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.render("pages/dashboard");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});
```

My `registerUser` controller:

```
const registerUser = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await pool.query("select * from find_user_by_email($1)", [
        email,
    ]);
    if (user.rowCount) {
        res.error = "User already exists";
        return next(500);
    }
    const saltHash = generatePassword(password);
    const response = await pool.query("select * from create_user($1, $2, $3)", [
        email,
        saltHash.salt,
        saltHash.hash,
    ]);
    if (response.rowCount) {
        req.session.user = { email: response.rows[0].create_user };
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/register");
    }
});
```

UPDATE(FIX):
It turns out redirects shouldn't be used when we are rendering template files. I replaced all `res.redirect` with `res.render`.

Comment: Don't call `next` after you called `res.redirect`.

Comment: I removed the ```next```, now it doesn't even load the pages. I also removed the else part from the ```sessionChecker```, it doesn't even load the pages. I must add that ```redirect``` to dashboard is getting called multiple times but never loading the dashboard page.

Comment: You shouldn't remove `next`, you just need to make sure you don't call it if you _also_ call `res.redirect`. The issue is in the middleware that's redirecting to `/dashboard` in your app code.

Comment: I don't think its getting called. It's in the else part.

Comment: It's in the first code block of your question.

Comment: Ok, now I'm not getting the error, but still it's not getting redirected to the dashboard. It keeps getting called like this ```GET /dashboard 302 249.152 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 251.018 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 249.149 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 250.563 ms - 64```

Comment: That's another issue. Please update your question or post a new one. But the issue is caused by your middleware not making a distinction between requests to `/dashboard` and any other request.